# Python: Parsing data containing both types of quotation as well as special characters

Tags: python, parsing, shlex

Hi All I am working on a project where I need to parse some data containing both " and ' quotation marks as well as special characters. While the data is confidential and therefore cannot be posted on here the text below replicates the issue.

```py
"""
Brian: "I am not the messiah" Arthur:\n\t "I say you are Lord and I should know I've followed a few"
```

The end goal is to get the text in the form:

```py
['Brian:', '"I am not the messiah"', 'Arthur:', '"I say you are Lord and I should know I've followed a few"']
```

That is to say all newline and tab characters removed, splitting on newlines (though this is read from a file so `.readlines()` takes care of that) and any spaces but not within double (`"`) quotation marks.

The code

```py
import shlex as sh
line_info = sh.split(line.removesuffix("\n").replace("\t", " "))
```

comes close to success but but fails to retain the quotations marks (I don't need the quotation marks themselves but I do need an indication the text was quoted for further processing)

Edit:

Original question had the example with all quoted phrases on separate lines to non-quoted ones. Unfortunately this is not the case in the file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem lies in the `shlex` module, stripping the quotation marks. But there is an easy solution with the extra argument `posix=False`. With this argument, the quotation marks are kept intact, see e.g. here:

```py
import io
import shlex

text = """
Brian: "I am not the messiah" Arthur:\n\t "I say you are Lord and I should know I've followed a few"
"""

result = []
for line in io.StringIO(text).readlines():
    line_info = shlex.split(line.removesuffix("\n").replace("\t", " "), posix=False)
    result.extend(line_info)

expectation = [
    'Brian:',
    '"I am not the messiah"',
    'Arthur:',
    '"I say you are Lord and I should know I\'ve followed a few"'
]

assert result == expectation
```

I am faking here the string as a file object to have the possibility to apply the `readlines`-method to be closer to your code, hopefully.

Comment: Thanks that works great and this reading a very small file into a pretty hefty process so the performance doesn't matter at all.

Comment: I would give you the upvote but I'm new to stack and don't have the rep for it yet.

Comment: Apologies there was an error in my example. Some of quoted phrases are not separated by newlines so a better example would have been:     Brian: \t"I am not the messiah" Arthur: \n\t "I say you are Lord and I should know I've followed a few"

Comment: Unfortunately this means your solution doesn't work (Apologies for the confusion It took me a while to notice the flaw in my example and as I haven't worked with StringIO I mistakenly assumed it was doing some of the processing)

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. I have updated the code. Luckily, it seems that you are very close to the solution and missed only one argument for the shlex parser. So my initial code changed significantly, now - but very close to your code.

Comment: works fantastic thanks, I thought I'd given it the tick already. Have done now